# interface syntax - unclear use of this

Tags: c#, object, interface

I couldn't find any explanation for the line in a red rectangle, could anyone help me breaking it down?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking in the documentation?..

Comment: indexer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/

Comment: yes but I couldn't find similar sintaxis , could you recommend me any link where I can find similar sintaxis?

Comment: Please edit question to include the code instead of an image

Answer (score 2):

The given interface defines an override for the [indexer operator (`[]`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index-operator). A simple example of use:

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

class PointCollection
{
    public List<Point> collection { get; set; }

    public Point this[int x, int y]
    {
        get => collection.FirstOrDefault(item => item.X == x && item.Y == y);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
var item = points[100, 200];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to replace Point by IColor, the problem is that in my exercise I can't add int x, and int y to my code (As you may see I need to complete my exercise filling the white background lines). How can I implement the get and set without having the x and y? thanks

Comment: @zeellos - I cannot solve your exercises for you but just give you leads. Your question is about understanding what the `this[]` means and this answer provides both a link to the documentation, a general example of use and also now that you know how its called you can keep on looking.. In addition your class shows no data structures for `[int x, int y]` to actually be relevant to..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answers to your question

```
public class MyImage : IImage
{
    private IColor[,] imageData = null;
    int w=0, h = 0;

    public MyImage(int width, int height, IColor defaultColor)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        imageData = new IColor[width, height];
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                imageData[i, j] = defaultColor;
            }
        }
    }

    public IColor this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            w = imageData.GetLength(0);
            h = imageData.GetLength(1);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            if ((w > 0 && w > x) && (h > 0 && h > y))
                return imageData[x, y];
            else
                return null;
        }

        set
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            if ((w > 0 && w > x) && (h > 0 && h > y))
                imageData[x, y] = value;
        }
    }
}

public interface IColor
{

}

public interface IImage
{
    IColor this[int x, int y] { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.